# How to make a comma separated string variable in a dataset a unique row/column name in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with approximately 100+ rows and 1 column. The one column denoting locations, is a comma separated string, recording multiple locations for each participant. There are between 3 and 60 locations recorded for each for each participant;

An example would be;

```
"ba1,xa2,ca3,fg58,ju59,hu60"
```

I have made a mini dataset below that reflects my real dataset

```
original_df <- data.frame(

row.names = c ("A1","B1","C1","D1","E1"),
  Location = c("AZ,Y12,-HG,AS:FG",
         "AS,-HG",
         "AS:FG,-OR,GF",
         "Y12,VB,-HI",
         "-OI:FG,JH,JI,Y12"))
```

Some of the locations are repeated across the different participants. Ideally, I would like to make each unique location a row name (or column name, either would be fine ) and would record whether the location is present/not present (or true/false) for each participant.

I've tried to make the dataset the I would like to make

```
ideal_df <- data.frame(

row.names = c("AZ","Y12","-HG","AS:FG","AS","-OR","GF","VB","-HI","-OI:FG","JH",  "JI"),
        A1 = c ("TRUE", "TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","F","F", "F","F","F","F","F","F"),
        B1 = c("F", "F", "TRUE","F", "TRUE","F", "F","F","F","F", "F","F"),
        C1 = c("F", "F", "F", "TRUE","F","TRUE", "TRUE","F","F","F", "F","F"),
        D1 = c("F", "TRUE","F","F","F","F","F","TRUE","TRUE","F", "F","F"),
        E1 = c("F", "F","F", "F","F","F", "F","F","F","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE"))
```

I have only recently started using R and have been very unsuccessful in trying to transform my dataset. Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We could reshape to 'long' format by splitting the column with `separate_rows`, then use `pivot_wider` to reshape back to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
original_df %>% 
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
    separate_rows(Location, sep=",") %>% 
    mutate(rn2 = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = rn2, 
        values_fn = list(rn2 = ~ length(.) > 0), values_fill = FALSE) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('Location')
```

-ouptut

```
         A1    B1    C1    D1    E1
AZ      TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Y12     TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
-HG     TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
AS:FG   TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
AS     FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
-OR    FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
GF     FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
VB     FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
-HI    FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
-OI:FG FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
JH     FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
JI     FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or in a single line with `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
 `colnames<-`(t(mtabulate(strsplit(original_df$Location, ",")) > 0), row.names(original_df))
          A1    B1    C1    D1    E1
-HG     TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
-HI    FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
-OI:FG FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
-OR    FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
AS     FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
AS:FG   TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
AZ      TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
GF     FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
JH     FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
JI     FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
VB     FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
Y12     TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

IN base R you could do:

```
a <- setNames(strsplit(original_df$Location, ','), rownames(original_df))
as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(a)) > 0)

         A1    B1    C1    D1    E1
-HG     TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
-HI    FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
-OI:FG FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
-OR    FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
AS     FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
AS:FG   TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
AZ      TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
GF     FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
JH     FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
JI     FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
VB     FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
Y12     TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```